# does sql automatically kill sleep processes or not?can i stop this action?

Tags: c#, sql

**Does SQL automatically kill sleeping processes?**

SQL terminates my program's process.
I dont want it. Is there any way to stop SQL from doing this?

```
select * from master.dbo.sysprocesses
```

My program's language is C#

---

(Copied in from answer below):

MY PROGRAM connect to sql.sql show my program connection in that list(select * from master.dbo.sysprocesses)

but its state is sleeping.after some minute sql remove the row that belong to my program.but my program still run.it should not remove it

Comment: can you clarify: do you mean it is killing your spid/connection? after what sort of interval is it dying? seconds? minutes? days?

Answer (score 0):

MY PROGRAM connect to sql.sql show my program connection in that list(select * from master.dbo.sysprocesses)

but its state is sleeping.after some minute sql remove the row that belong to my program.but my program still run.it should not remove it

Comment: Why not?  If it's not doing anything why not recycle it?

Comment: Also, this should be an edit or a comment on your original question, not an answer.

Comment: thanks.i know the reason that is behind this action.but i want to stop this for my programs connection .is there any way?

Comment: Honestly, I cannot think of a good reason for this.  If you have a requirement for this, there's probably something else wrong. If you can elaborate on your requirements in the question, we may be able to help.

Comment: i want to know my program is running or not by using sql.if my program is open but user dont do anything,I want to know it is open by using sql